# What is the name of this plot and, roughly, how can it be plotted using ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I would like to implement a block histogram like the one above. What would be right `geom_**()` function to use? Moreover, is there a `geom` function that can allow me to add icons along the scale like the one shown in the picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a histogram with some extra decoration. We can get close to this effect by using `geom_histogram`'s fill and color arguments for vertical boundaries, along with `geom_hline` to overlay horizontal boundaries.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(obs = 1:100, val = rnorm(100))

g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = val)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = 'lightgray', color = 'white') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 10, 1), color = 'white') +
  theme_classic()
print(g)
```

[image]

I'm not sure that it's possible to add graphics to the axes, at least within base ggplot.